# How to Modify Tile Data in mapbox-gl-js ? (callback or any structure to decode tile binary data)

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

**summery ->**
in our company, we use our own vector-tile-servers for displaying base maps. we encode both tile-url and Tile data in some way for protection.
now, we are going to start using mapbox-gl-js in our webApps.

**problem ->**
I cannot find the callback or any solution to modifying each tile data after they've got fetched. it seems there is no solution defined in docs or forums.

**what I am seeking for ->**
if there is any solution defined already, please leave a sample or the address to it's doc for me.
this is really vital. if u got any soluttion for this problem pls let me know about it.

Comment: I don’t think Mapbox GL’s has anything that could help you. Maybe a proxy server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after lots of googling and trying, and also based on this [issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/9840), I assure you currently there is no way but modifying source of mapboxgl-js.